# What dishes are paired with agnolini in Mantuan cuisine?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine, menu-planning

I am preparing [agnolini alla mantovana](http://www.cucinamantovana.it/agnoli1.htm) and I would like to pair the dish with a second course and side in classic Mantuan style.

[image: agnolini] <sup>[source](http://www.consiglialimentari.it/article/Agnolini-in-brodo/4.htm)</sup>

[Mantuan cuisine](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucina_mantovana) is famous for its "set meals".

What are the classic pairings, in the sense of pairing tastes but also of reuse of resources, for example if I pair it with boiled meat, I can use the stock with the agnolini? I'd rather avoid the boiled meat in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

The Google translation of this article was a bit rough, so I went through it for you and added some links to recipes and such. I hope this helps. I learned a bit myself. That Torta Sbrisolona shall be mine!

The recipe for Agnolini doesn't call for stock, but I bet you could use it in that preparation as long as you reduce it enough. You don't want a runny filling.

Source. http://www.ristorantimantova.info/piatti-tipici-mantovani

> The Mantuan kitchen is closely linked with the history and traditions of its neighboring cities. The
>   geographical location of Mantua, squeezed between Venice and Emilia
>   Romagna, characterizes the kitchen. The ruling Gonzaga dynasty heavily
>   influenced the culinary traditions of Mantua. The Mantuan kitchen is
>   often referred to as "Of the Princes and the People" because it
>   combines the refinement of Gonzaga kitchen with dishes typical of the
>   peasant folk.
>
> Among the typical dishes of Mantua, the real backbones are the first
>   courses.
>
> Among the dishes are the very Mantuan ["Miller's
>   Risotto"](http://italianfood.about.com/od/meatyrisotti/r/blr1042.htm),
>   the
>   [Agnolini](http://www.italy-recipes.com/ricette/dettaglio_ita.asp?index=3012&titolo=agnolini-mantovani) [(picture)](http://foodografia.tumblr.com/post/22840352111/agnolini-mantuan-fresh-stuffed-pasta)
>   and [Tortelli di
>   Zucca](http://www.italian-food-recipes.net/2007/01/tortelli-di-zucca-primo.html),
>   a true symbol of the delicious local cuisine.
>
> As for the main courses, the Mantuan cuisine offers both fish dishes,
>   such as catfish, trout, pike and saltarei [the famous Sauced
>   Pike](http://www3.lastampa.it/cucina/sezioni/dove/osterie-ditalia/articolo/lstp/426858/)
>   and meat dishes, such as roast beef, poultry and game, stews, pot
>   roasts and boiled him.
>
> Another highlight of the delicious local cuisine are the cold cuts and
>   sausages. In addition to the famous Mantuan salami, one must not skip
>   a tasting of [Ciccioli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciccioli), the
>   [Gras
>   Pistàs](http://www.toddenglish.com/Recipes/Sauces/graspistas_card.html),
>   the sausages used for [Risotto alla
>   Mantovana](http://italianfood.about.com/od/meatyrisotti/r/blr0469.htm)
>   and, especially in winter,
>   [Cotechino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotechino).
>
> Equally famous are the DOP (“Denominazione di Origine Protetta” or
>   "Protected Designation of Origin") Mantuan cheeses Grana Padano,
>   Parmigiano Reggiano and Provolone and the condiment [Mustard
>   Mantovana](http://italianfood.about.com/od/saucescondiments/r/blr0833.htm).
>
> As for fruits and vegetables, country kitchens are famous for their
>   cultivation of melons and pears.
>
> Desserts, along with the first course, are the real highlight of the
>   Mantuan cuisine, such as [La Torta
>   Sbrisolona](http://thecookieshopinenglish.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/the-dessert-i-couldnt-have-torta-sbrisolona/),
>   [La Torta delle
>   Rose](https://ritamonti.com/theitalianwayoflife/la-torta-delle-rose),
>   and [La Torta
>   Elvezia](http://alenakogotkova.livejournal.com/36303.html#In%20English)
>
> We must also say a few words about Mantuan wines: Denominazione di
>   Origine Controllata [Lambrusco Mantovano red
>   wine](http://www.wine-searcher.com/regions-lambrusco+mantovano), Colli
>   Morenici white wines, and [Garda Colli Mantovani
>   wines](http://www.wine-searcher.com/regions-garda+colli+mantovani).